# Faster method to get _set.all() values in m2m relationships with Django

Tags: python, django

I read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) and have one question.

Here we get all articles:

```
p2.article_set.all()
```

What the faster and low-number_of_queries_to_db way to get set of ids of that articles?

I use this code:

```
set(i['id'] for i in p2.article_set.all().values('id'))
```

Does it correct or there is another fastest method to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fastest way to do it is to use the [`values_list()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method:

```
set(p2.article_set.all().values_list('id', flat=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it shorter:

```
p2.article_set.only('id').all()
```

But I think SQL query will be the same.